# Minimize number of pairs covering all the elements of two lists

Tags: combinatorics

Given two lists of elements, that are paired in a specific way, e.g:

```
  list1 list2
1    A    X
2    A    Y
3    A    Z
4    B    Y
5    C    X
6    C    Y
```

How could I select the minimum number of possible pairs covering all the elements in both lists?

I hope there is an algorithm that finds the optimal answer, but I do not have a math background.

In this case, the optimal answer would be:

```
  list1 list2
3    A    Z
4    B    Y
5    C    X
```

Comment: I think you mean "select the **minimum** number of pairs containing **every** element from each list"

Comment: Is your priority to select as many pairs as possible that share no entries, or to select the minimum number of pairs to cover all the distinct entries in each list?  Or something else?  Please clarify.

Comment: My priority is to select the minimum number of pairs that cover all the elements in both lists. I have edited the main text

Comment: This is known as the *minimum edge cover problem*.